# How to vary `<options>` in `<select>` elements in AngularJS Forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on something which requires to come up with different options for different selections as list in forms.

for example:
If I select DR9 in System field, it has to show only 100,400,500 clients. same for QR9 - only 400 and 500.

But in my case, it's showing(100,400,500,400,500) repetitively.

Here is my code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    
    <div ng-app="">
     Password Reset
      <form>
        <br><label>System:</label> 
     <select ng-model="myVar">
      <option value = "DR9">DR9</option>
      <option value = "QR9">QR9</option>
      <option value = "PR3">PR3</option>
     </select>
     <br><br>
     <label>Client:</label>
     <select>
      <div ng-switch="myVar">
       <div ng-switch-when="DR9">
        <option>100</option>
        <option>400</option>
        <option>500</option>
       </div>
       <div ng-switch-when="QR9">
        <option>400</option>
        <option>500</option>
       </div>
      </div>
     </select>
     </form>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code loads `angular.js` twice with different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template can be simplified by using the [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#overview) directive:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = "PR3";
    $scope.otherOptions = otherOptions("PR3");
    $scope.updateOtherOptions = function(myVar) {
        $scope.otherOptions = otherOptions(myVar);
    };
    
    function otherOptions(myVar) {
       switch (myVar) {
           case "DR9":  return [100,400,500];
           case "QR9":  return [400,500];
           default: return [100,400,500];
       };
    };
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Password Reset
  <form>
    <br>
    <label>System:</label> 
    <select ng-model="myVar" ng-change="updateOtherOptions(myVar)">
        <option value = "DR9">DR9</option>
        <option value = "QR9">QR9</option>
        <option value = "PR3">PR3</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Client options={{otherOptions}}
    <br>
    <label>Client:</label>
    <select ng-model="otherSel" ng-options="sel for sel in otherOptions">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
    </select>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `ngOptions` attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of `<option>` elements for the `<select>` element using the array or object obtained by evaluating the `ngOptions` comprehension expression.

When an item in the `<select>` menu is selected, the array element or object property represented by the selected option will be bound to the model identified by the `ngModel` directive.

Optionally, a single hard-coded `<option>` element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the `<select>` element. This element will then represent the `null` or "not selected" option.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-options Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)
- [AngularJS API Reference - Using `select` with `ngOptions` and setting a default value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value)
- [AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Comment: Thanks george, this was perfect. Could you please explain ?

Comment: Added explaination and references.

Answer (score 1):

You cant apply `ng-switch` to a `div` with `options` instead add `ng-switch` to a `div` and apply `ng-switch-when` to `select`

```html
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
<div ng-app="">
 Password Reset
  <form>
    <br><label>System:</label> 
 <select ng-model="myVar">
  <option value = "DR9">DR9</option>
  <option value = "QR9">QR9</option>
  <option value = "PR3">PR3</option>
 </select>
 <br><br>
 <label>Client:</label>
    <div ng-switch="myVar">
    <select ng-switch-when="DR9">
    <option>100</option>
    <option>400</option>
    <option>500</option>  
 </select>
     <select ng-switch-when="QR9">
     <option>400</option>
    <option>500</option>
 </select>
      <select ng-switch-default>
    <option>100</option>
    <option>400</option>
    <option>500</option>  
 </select>
    </div>

     </form>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `<form>` is duplicated.

Comment: Thanks srini, But the code given by you doesn't meet the criteria.